# Changing Default Currency in shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

If this question seems like a possible duplicate, I'm sorry. please link me to the original.

I am developing a shopping cart with php and mysql.

In the admin panel, multiple currency types can be set, and new currency types can be added. It will have a default currency and a coversion rate.
My problem is when changing the default currency type.

This is what my tables look like

```
**Currency**
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    CurrencyType        ConversionRate           IsDefault
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       type1                 -                      y
2       type2                 2.0                    n
3       type3                 3.0                    n
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Product**
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID     Rate        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      100
2      200      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here for the price for product 1 will be

```
(100) for currency type1
(100 * 2.0) for currency type2
(100 * 3.0) for currency type3
```

In the admin panel, the conversion rates will added with respect to the default currency type.

Here while changing the default type, I can update the conversion rates in the currency table.
But I am having to update the rate in the product table. Changing the rates for all products in the product table, made me feel that I am wrong.

Is there any other better way to do.? please advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the product table instead of doing these calculations in php?  It seems superfluous.

Comment: The admin will enter the rate of new products in the default currency.

Comment: Sorry alex couldn't get you. Can u explain it.?

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have misunderstood your original intention.  So if you decided to switch to a default of CurrencyType type2, the ConversionRate of type1 would change to be .5, correct?  And you'd like the Rate of products 1 and 2 to change to 200 and 400, respectively?

Comment: yes, conv rate of type 1 to 0.5..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with which i need not update the product table.. I am gonna have a HIDDEN currency type which will be the default for the calculations.. The rate in the product table will be always be *1 to this currency type

Can make the necessary calculations in the admin panel so that the admin can still enter the rate of the new product in his default currency type..

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand your question I am relatively sure that you'll have to update both tables.  If you simply wanted to display the table to the user in a different conversion rate but keep the underlying cost the same, then you could always store the value in `CurrencyType` `type1` but convert it to `type2` or `type3` in php when displaying it to the user.  But if you want the actual values in the `Product` table to update when you update the default `CurrencyType`, and not just the way that they are displayed to the user, then you'll have to update both tables.

Luckily, SQL makes this very easy since all you're effectively doing is multiplying the current Rate value by the ConversionRate you're changing it to.  So if you have a php variable storing the `ConversionRate` of the new `CurrencyType` before you make it default:

```
UPDATE Product
SET Rate = Rate * oldConversionRate
```

should update all rows in the Product table with the new `Product` rates.  Let me know if that was confusingly worded or you'd like more clarification.

Comment: updating the entire product table is not a good practise rite.?

Comment: @ravz it would be a nicer solution to store all the product rates on the database in one `CurrencyType`, then display them to the client using the `ConversionType` they have selected.  That way both the `ConversionRates` from the `Currency` table and the `Rates` in the `Product` table should never change.  Your php code will simply multiply the item `Rate` in the `Product` table by the `ConversionRate` of the default `CurrencyType`.